# Confusion about the Proof that every subspace of V is part of a direct sum equal to V

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

In Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, he proves that statement in the title however only addresses finite-dimensional vector spaces in the proof.

My question: Does it also apply to infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

His proof:
[image]

My confusing arrises as the statement is the part: "every subspace of V is a direct..." To me, it seems V is just an arbitrary vector space that can be finite or infinite dimensional, however he only proves it for finite-dimensional spaces.

Please note that this is relatively early on in the book so I feel like if it is true for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, we don't know enough yet which is why he (Axler) doesn't prove it for them as well.

Comment: "Every subspace of V" does not imply that the result holds for infinite vector spaces as well, there is a difference between "every component of a thing" and "a component of any/every thing"  and since he specifies, "let V be finite dimensional" there is in fact nothing lacking from his proof

Comment: Nothing in the statement applies to infinite dimensional $V,$ as written. I’m not sure why you treat “every subspace of $V$” to imply the possibility that $V$ is infinite dimensional, when the supposition already is precisely the opposite.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with the previous two commenters and see your confusion.  If you take the blue text as part of the theorem statement, then it does appear that Axler is claiming the result for all vector spaces (including those of infinite dimensions).  That said, I suspect a better way to interpret the blue is as an easy-to-remember slogan, while the text beneath the blue is the actual theorem being claimed.

Comment: @Carlyle you are right I stated myself wrong in the question however other statements in the book that only relate to finite-dimensional spaces always state that V is finite dimensional. (Technically, that is only true 1 theorem, but the other 2-3 state spanning lists which imply finite dimensional spaces)

Comment: If your confusion is with the statement heading "Every subspace of $V$..." - the heading is not meant to be a precise statement, just a general indication of the theorem. To get the precise statement, you should read the text underneath, where it is explicitly restricted to finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Ted Will do from now on, thank you

Comment: In my book Linear Algebra Done Right, each theorem has a one-line title in blue type that is meant to be an informal statement of or about the theorem. The precise statement of the theorem is then given below the one line that is in blue type. For the theorem in question here, the precise statement does include the hypothesis that V is finite-dimensional. I restricted attention to finite-dimensional vector spaces whenever not doing so would require using the Axiom of Choice or Zorn's Lemma. The main focus of linear algebra is on finite-dimensional vector spaces and linear maps on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that proof uses the fact that every finite-dimensional vector space has a basis. However, the statement “every vector space has a basis”  neither can be proved to be true nor it can be proved to be false; it depends upon which set theory you are using. Also, that proof from Axlers's textbook uses the fact that every basis of a subspace can be extended to a basis of the whole space, assuming that the whole space is finite-dimensional. Again, this statement neither can be proved to be true nor it can be proved to be false.

However, in the specific case in which your set theory is ZFC (Zermelo-Fraenkel theory with the axiom of choice), then both statements can be proved to be true.

Comment: “However, the statement ‘every vector space has a basis’ is neither true nor false” That is an extremely strong philosophical claim. What is objectively true is that “every vector space has a basis” is independent of ZF unless ZF is inconsistent. But all we need is classical logic to say that it is either true or false that all vector spaces have a basis.

Comment: @MarkSaving I also wrote that “it depends upon which set theory you are using”. In ZFC, it is a true statement. But there are extensions of ZF with respect to which the statement is false.

Comment: You are confusing provable and true. It cannot be the case that a statement is neither true nor false; this violates the law of noncontradiction. However, it can be the case that a statement is neither provable nor disprovable.

Comment: @MarkSaving I have edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you for spending your time improving my answer.

Comment: You’re welcome. Thank you for tolerating my pedantry.